# pgAdmin - aceptar valores concretos en una columna

Tags: pgadmin

Estoy empezando con pgAdmin y quiero crear una columna que sólo admite 3 valores.

Las condiciones de la tabla son:

- discipline_id: entero no nulo. Clave primaria
- discipline_name: cadena variable 50 caracteres no nulo
- discipline_type: cadena variable 10 caracteres no nulo. Solamente puede tener los valores RUN, JUMP o THROW.
- object_type cadena fija 10 caracteres no nulo

La tabla que he creado es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_discipline (
    discipline_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    discipline_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    discipline_type  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    object_type CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_tb_discipline PRIMARY KEY (discipline_id),
    CONSTRAINT ck_discipline_type CHECK (RUN OR JUMP OR THROW),
);
```

Es correcto usar el `CHECK` de esta forma?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

diría que te falta indicar el campo discipline_type
CONSTRAINT ck_discipline_type CHECK (discipline_type IS RUN OR JUMP OR THROW)
Tambien sobra la ultima coma antes del );

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).